# Pandas: select rows were a column has lists that are not empty

Tags: python, pandas, select

I have a data frame with a column that values are lists. I need to select rows where these lists are not empty:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [('words', ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foobar', 'helter', 'skelter']),
         ('counts', [[1,2,3], [], [5,8], [13,21,34,55], [89], [] ])
         ]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(data)
df

Output:
    words   counts
0   foo     [1, 2, 3]
1   bar         []
2   baz         [5, 8]
3   foobar  [13, 21, 34, 55]
4   helter  [89]
5   skelter     []
```

Selecting this way fails:

```
df[df['counts'] != []]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-db8067c8ac7b> in <module>()
----> 1 df[df['counts'] != []]

/Users/user/usr/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in wrapper(self, other, axis)
    859 
    860             with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
--> 861                 res = na_op(values, other)
    862             if is_scalar(res):
    863                 raise TypeError('Could not compare %s type with Series' %

/Users/user/usr/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in na_op(x, y)
    763 
    764         if is_object_dtype(x.dtype):
--> 765             result = _comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY(op, x, y)
    766         else:
    767 

/Users/user/usr/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in _comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY(op, x, y)
    741             y = y.values
    742 
--> 743         result = lib.vec_compare(x, y, op)
    744     else:
    745         result = lib.scalar_compare(x, y, op)

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.vec_compare (pandas/_libs/lib.c:14284)()

ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 6 vs 0
```

Other things like `df.query` do not work in this case as well. Any ideas how to solve this? Why it is not possible to compare pandas cell value with an empty list?

Comment: `df[df.counts.astype(bool)]` However, this is a dup.  finding dup.

Comment: pandas typically does not work well with columns of arrays of variable length.

Comment: simply change [] to "" should work. Like this df[df['counts'] != ""]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it that is hacky but works:

```
df[ df.counts.str.len() > 0 ]
```